# Question about why I can't compare an input() against a list

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
listA = ['one', 'two', 'three']

phrase = input('> ').lower()

if phrase == str(listA[0]):
   #do something
elif phrase == str(listA[1]):
   #do something
elif phrase == str(listA[2]):
   #do something
```

I'm not sure why after I input 'one', I get the following error "name 'one' is not defined".

Still learning and googling, any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What is your Python version? You are using a *dead* version, switch to Python 3.

Comment: Use this for python2: phrase = raw_input('> ').lower()